# Windows Driver Kit, what does "storage must be resident" mean?

Tags: wdk

Are they refering to non-pagable memory or what? I cannot find any reference to *resident* storage.

Comment: Why the down vote if the question has a valid answer, if you don't know anything about Windows driver development then just move on...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resident memory, as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) simply referes to memory that is not currently paged. Memory allocated from the `NonPagedPool` is for instance always resident while memory allocated from the `PagedPool` can be resident but you have to check that the memory hasn't been paged out before you use it (depending on the context IRQL requirements).